# Bad video recording quality

Tags: raspivid

I am trying to record a video using raspivid but when I am playing
the video has bad quality and shorter than it should be

raspivid -t 30000 -o vid.h264

Comment: How are you playing the video?

Comment: What is your memory and CPU usage during recording? Try `top`.